#  Three body problem with point interactions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physics, mp.mathematical-physics, reference-request, bibliography

I've studied the HVZ theorem for the three body problem interacting with regular potentials. I'd like to extend this result to the three body problem with point interactions (delta potentials).
Is there anyone who have studied this problem and knows some references about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Few-Body Systems **38**, 125 (2006):](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0604003) *On critical stability of three quantum charges interacting through delta potentials*, H.D. Cornean, P. Duclos, B. Ricaud.

> We consider three one dimensional
>   quantum, charged and spinless
>   particles interacting through delta
>   potentials. We derive sufficient
>   conditions which guarantee the
>   existence of at least one bound state.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm studying the problem in three dimension, but I'll surely read rour article.